# How do I achieve a header image like this in CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: This is how I want to style it.]

I am trying to style this is Bootstrap Modal. However, I am not getting it quite right.

This is my code so far :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="crowdmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" style="background: url('satinweave.png')">
      <div class="modal-body" style="background: url( 'picy-modal.png'); background-position: top; background-repeat: no-repeat;">

        <p> cool text... </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Got it!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the image link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0s4G.png

It would be great if somehow it can be made responsive as well.

Any help or a nudge in the right direction would be helpful!.

Comment: What part of the CSS structure are you stuck on? How far have you got? It's a very good idea to put styles into a CSS stylesheet rather than as page inline styles.

Comment: a fiddle with the actual result? or at least a screenshot of it? can be helpfull

Comment: And that baby is about to vomit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`background-size:contain`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) to make sure that the `background-image` will take the full width - no more no less.

Now, you can add `padding-top` to `.modal-content` and there you go.

**Demo**

```js
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

```css
.modal-content {
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/KP1I8LA.png) no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  padding-top:40%;
}

.modal-header,.modal-body {
  border:0 !important;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <!--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>-->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/tefufu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: This seems like the correct answer and it is working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: It works correctly until you scale it down, when you set a fixed padding-top on it, the text will look out of place.. Just something to keep in mind

Comment: I just was updated my answer. @Kjarri is right and I replaced the fix `padding` to relative (by percents).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular image tag instead of using the background-image to get the result you want

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="crowdmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KP1I8LA.png" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%;"/>
    <p>
    cool text...
    </p>
      <div class="modal-body" style="background: url( 'http://i.imgur.com/KP1I8LA.png'); background-position: top; background-repeat: no-repeat;">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Got it!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kjarriho/dLw6o6hc/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.modal-body{min-height:300px;width:100%;background-size:cover}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="crowdmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" style="background: url('satinweave.png')">
      <div class="modal-body" style="background: url( 'http://i.imgur.com/KP1I8LA.png'); background-position: top; background-repeat: no-repeat;">

        <p> cool text... </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Got it!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just try this code.

Answer (score 0):

Images can act responsive on adding class - img-responsive, example:

```
<img src="some.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/f6M7Te2AclpznCzlpyjZ?p=preview

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want exactly: See DEMO

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
       Image
      </button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
           <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KP1I8LA.png" class="img-responsive" />
       
            <div class="modal-body">
            Some cool text
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```